# Using '@' in parameters names

Tags: c#, .net, verbatim-string

I know the usage of verbatim prefix to avoid having to escape special characters all the time. For example:

```
string s = @"c:\myPath";
```

However I just realized it is possible having something similar for parameters names. Example:

```
public void aMethod(int i, DateTime @date){

}
```

I wonder why is that syntax correct and in which case can this be useful..

Comment: It allows the use of *reserved words*

Comment: You could use `@params` or also `@for` as variable-name, however for `date` it makes no sense at all.

Comment: Thanks guys. Sorry for my ignorance..

Comment: This might be a subtle distinction, but does it actually allow the use of reserved words, or does it just create a new variable that looks like a reserved word, but with an @ in front of it?  You can have some pretty crazy characters for variable names, using most of Unicode.  @ may just be a valid character for an identifier.

Comment: It doesn't allow reserved words but create a new variable name (it might be an underscore too).

Comment: Interesting. I just found the spec https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664670.aspx and it actually does do a bit of transformation on the identifier. The variables '@test' and 'test' will actually be treated the same. But this is true only if the variable names starts with @, it won't be ignored if it is *inside* the string.

Comment: This is particularly useful when using HTML helpers in ASP.NET MVC to define properties that are reserved words eg `@Html.ActionLink("My Link", "MyAction", "MyController", null, new { @class = "myClass myClass2" })` where class would usually be interpreted as a reserved word.